# How to use include in GNUmakefile

Tags: gnu-make

I have a makefile called test.mak and another one just called GNUmakefile

The way I execute the test.mak from command line is "make test.mak arg1". Now I would like to execute it in the GNUmakefile. I know I can use "include" so I did (in GNUmakefile)

"-include test.mak arg1" but the arg1 is treated like another makefile but how do I pass the argument to test.mak?

Thanks

Comment: Typing `make test.mak arg1` on the command line will casue GNU Make to read the `GNUMakefile` and attempt to build targets called `test.mak` and `arg1`. It does NOT "execute test.mak" in any way, shape, or form.  Using `make -include test.mak arg1` gives "invalid option -- 'c'".  So the question makes no sense...

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you just take the argument in GNUmakefile and since they share the same variable, test.mak should be getting the argument.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few errors in your question that need to be cleared up:

First, to invoke make using test.mak, you should use

```
make -f test.mak arg1
```

the "-f" tells make the name of the makefile to use.  Without it, make will try to use GNUmakefile, makefile, and Makefile (in that order).

Second, the "arg1" on your command line tells make which target you are trying to make.  It is an argument to the make program, but not to the makefile itself.  Because of that, it's not necessary to try to "pass" arg1 to test.mak on your include line.  The "include" directive's parameters are the files to be included.

The line

```
include test.mak arg1
```

tries to include two files (named test.mak and arg1).

What you really want to do in GNUmakefile is just

```
include test.mak
```

which will allow you to type

```
make arg1
```

to create the "arg1" target using your implicitly-named GNUmakefile.